# How to get some kind of progress meter on Yum downloads?

Tags: yum

Is there a way to get some kind of progress meter when using YUM, for the actual downloading of the RPMs?

I'm talking after YUM has done its thing with searching repos, and asking you if you want to do the download.

On large downloads, all you get is the string "Downloading" starring back at you for a long time without any indication of anything going on.

Thank you.

Comment: Yum has _always_ had a progress meter the few times I've used Fedora or CentOS. Are you behind a corporate proxy server that doesn't report "Content-Length"? Do tools like `wget` show a progress meter?

Comment: I'm on CentOS7, which is a bit old. YUM there, has progress meters for downloading repository data, but not for actually downloading RPMs.